# How to Retrieve Text from Textbox in Android widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm at the very early stage of learning Android. Can anyone tell me how I can use the text written in a Text box by user?

I'm trying to use getText() method but finding it confusing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

getText should do it.

you maybe need a string cast?

what is the code you using @ the moment?

example:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourId);

String editTextStr = editText.getText().toString()
```

docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText(

Answer (score 2):

```
TextBox t = (TextBox)findViewById(R.id.textboxid)
String s = "";
s = t.getText().toString();
```

Here you can get content of textbox

Answer (score 1):

I think what might be confusing him is that `getText()` doesn't return a string. You have to do `getText().toString()`

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for `TextView`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

`getText` and `setText` methods are avaialbe in this class to set and get text value.

Answer (score -2):

yes you need to retrieve the text by using getText() method. What is it that you find confusing here?

In short you need to say Textview.getText()

Comment: getText().toString()